# arquillian, wildfly change datasource to mysql - error missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: mysql, wildfly, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

i have working arquillian tests that use default h2/mem data base. now i want to switch to my sql.
I first copied `mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar` to `standalone/deployments`. The log confirmed proper deployment. I also tried to setup the mysql datasource via wildfly's admin console and it worked fine (i did connection test but didn't add the datasource).
I want to keep the datasource setup within project's test. So i added the data source to `src/test/resources/test-ds.xml`:

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">

<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql"
    pool-name="moritzTimetracker-test" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moritztimetracker</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

The `src/test/resources/META-INF/test-persistence.xml` looks like this:

```
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But if i run the test i get exception:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: test.war
...
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_1_33-bin_jar]"]}
```

The log says:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.reference-factory.java:jboss/datasources/moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql] 
      service jboss.data-source.reference-factory.java:jboss/datasources/moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql] 
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_1_33-bin_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/moritzTimetrackerTestDSmysql] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#primary".__FIRST_PHASE__ (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE]
```

How to correctly setup mysql as data source?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it is very badly documented i viewed the standalone.xml after i created the data source via the admin web interface. Setting the mysql datasource this way works fine:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testDSmysql"
    pool-name="test" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

See "drive-class" and "driver" - it is very different than stuff you read in documentation?!

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems correct (I mean data source and persistence xml).

But please check whether you are deploying `test-ds.xml` file along with your app in every test case. I mean:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml")  /* CRUCIAL STEP */
            ...
}
```

In this way, your data source definition is deployed with every micro deployment of your EJBs.